# How to know in Xcode how much memory occupied by my object graph?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, instruments

I have one big object graph. It begins from one root object and its properties are arrays which consist of other objects and so on.

I want to know how much memory is eating by this graph at all. Have Xcode any instrument that will show me this information by root object (maybe something like tree of all my objects)?

Or maybe it is possible to calculate its size programmatically at runtime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223560/how-to-find-the-size-of-any-object-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Try Instruments by running your project with `Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Object Allocation`.

Comment: Instrument "Object Allocation" shows information about all objects and groups them by type. How can I sort out objects that belong to my object graph?
Maybe I don't know something about this instrument?