# How to calculate total size of NSDictionary object?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, malloc, sizeof

How to calculate total size of `NSDictionary` object?
i have 3000 StudentClass objects in `NSDictionary` with different keys. And i want to calculate total size of dictionary in KB.
I used `malloc_size()` but it always return 24 (`NSDictionary` contain either 1 object or 3000 object)
`sizeof()` also returns always same.

Comment: Here is simular question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223560/how-to-find-the-size-of-any-object-in-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to get all the keys of the Dictionary in an array and then iterate the array to find the size, it might give you the total size of the keys inside the dictionary.

```
NSArray *keysArray = [yourDictionary allValues];
id obj = nil;
int totalSize = 0;

for(obj in keysArray)
{
    totalSize += malloc_size(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also find this way:

Objective C

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"a": @"Apple",@"b": @"bApple",@"c": @"cApple",@"d": @"dApple",@"e": @"eApple", @"f": @"bApple",@"g": @"cApple",@"h": @"dApple",@"i": @"eApple"};

NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:dict forKey:@"dictKey"];
[archiver finishEncoding];

NSInteger bytes=[data length];
float kbytes=bytes/1024.0;
NSLog(@"%f Kbytes",kbytes);
```

Swift 4

```
let dict: [String: String] = [
    "a": "Apple", "b": "bApple", "c": "cApple", "d": "dApple", "e": "eApple", "f": "bApple", "g": "cApple", "h": "dApple", "i": "eApple"
]

let data = NSMutableData()
let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
archiver.encode(dict, forKey: "dictKey")
archiver.finishEncoding()

let bytes = data.length
let kbytes = Float(bytes) / 1024.0

print(kbytes)
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to calculate the size of big `NSDictionary`, I think, would be converting it to `NSData` and get the size of the data. Good Luck!

Comment: By converting to NSData can we calculate the correct size of NSDictionary object in Bytes? Or it gives the converted NSData object's size, which is not the same with NSDictionary object's size?

Answer (score 2):

Might be useful to convert to NSData if your dictionary contains standard classes (eg. NSString) and not custome ones:

```
NSDictionary *yourdictionary = ...;
NSData * data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:yourdictionary
    format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:NULL];    
NSLog(@"size of yourdictionary: %d", [data length]);
```